# Deserializing nested JSON C# and Bind to XAML ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, json, xaml, windows-phone-8

i need to deserializing nested json string to Xaml

my Json

```
{
   "status":1,
   "message":"sussess",
   "Task_details":[
      {
         "task_id":"237",
         "created_f_id":"100001",
         "task_description":"task description",
         "due_date":"2014-01-08 04:59:30",
         "alert":"2",
         "status":"1",
         "postedon":"2014-01-07 11:29:29",
         "updatedon":"2014-01-07 11:29:29",
         "comments":[
            {
               "task_comment_id":"367",
               "f_id":"100001588960161",
               "comment":"sdfghhjfdsa",
               "created_date":"2014-01-07 11:29:29",
               "updated_date":"2014-01-07 11:29:29"
            }
         ],
         "followers":[
            {
               "f_id":"1000011"
            },
            {
               "f_id":"100004288170082"
            },
            {
               "f_id":"184685"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "task_id":"150",
         "created_f_id":"184680",
         "task_description":"testing",
         "due_date":"2013-12-30 02:39:00",
         "alert":"0",
         "status":"1",
         "postedon":"2013-12-30 09:10:22",
         "updatedon":"2013-12-30 09:10:22",
         "comments":[
            {
               "task_comment_id":"205",
               "f_id":"184385",
               "comment":"comment test",
               "created_date":"2013-12-30 09:10:22",
               "updated_date":"2013-12-30 09:10:22"
            }
         ],
         "followers":[
            {
               "f_id":"1846806385"
            },
            {
               "f_id":"100565"
            },
            {
               "f_id":"100001561"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

this json Data i need to Show in List Box , 
and the List Box Ui is Looking Like this Image

[image]

Im New to Wp8 development , what is the Best Way to Bind this Nested Json Data List Box , Im Facing Problem at How Bind that Follower List Images (Below 2,3 member I need to Show there Images More than that I need to Show Like 3 Images + 4Member ) to ListBox 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to deserialize the json string, that for you can use `Json.NET` - if you need a c# class pattern, use [this](http://json2csharp.com). Then you need to create a `DataContext` for your view (the page) and create a property in this to store your deserialzed json object. Your `DataContext` should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Then in the XAML create your `ListBox` and bind its `ItemsSource` property to the property in your DataContext. The next step is to create an `ItemTemplate` as a `DataTemplate` to style the ListBox's items just as you like then to look them like.

For your follower list you simply have to do the same, but instead of creating a new `DataContext` just use the properties of your binded items.

Comment: Yes But i Need Code , Because im New to Development an Wp8 to , Facing    prob at Binding Followers List Images in Xaml

Answer (score 0):

If you go to http://json2csharp.com/ and paste your json in there you will get the following objects

```
public class Comment
{
    public string task_comment_id { get; set; }
    public string f_id { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public string created_date { get; set; }
    public string updated_date { get; set; }
}

public class Follower
{
    public string f_id { get; set; }
}

public class TaskDetail
{
    public string task_id { get; set; }
    public string created_f_id { get; set; }
    public string task_description { get; set; }
    public string due_date { get; set; }
    public string alert { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string postedon { get; set; }
    public string updatedon { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> comments { get; set; }
    public List<Follower> followers { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int status { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<TaskDetail> Task_details { get; set; }
}
```

Add all these classes to your project. In the backend you could do something like

```
var jsonString = @"{
   "status":1,
   "message":"sussess",
   "Task_details":[
      {
         "task_id":"237",
         "created_f_id":"100001",
         "task_description":"task description",
         "due_date":"2014-01-08 04:59:30",
         "alert":"2",
         "status":"1",
         "postedon":"2014-01-07 11:29:29",
         "updatedon":"2014-01-07 11:29:29",
         "comments":[
            {
               "task_comment_id":"367",
               "f_id":"100001588960161",
               "comment":"sdfghhjfdsa",
               "created_date":"2014-01-07 11:29:29",
               "updated_date":"2014-01-07 11:29:29"
            }
         ],
         "followers":[
            {
               "f_id":"1000011"
            },
            {
               "f_id":"100004288170082"
            },
            {
               "f_id":"184685"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "task_id":"150",
         "created_f_id":"184680",
         "task_description":"testing",
         "due_date":"2013-12-30 02:39:00",
         "alert":"0",
         "status":"1",
         "postedon":"2013-12-30 09:10:22",
         "updatedon":"2013-12-30 09:10:22",
         "comments":[
            {
               "task_comment_id":"205",
               "f_id":"184385",
               "comment":"comment test",
               "created_date":"2013-12-30 09:10:22",
               "updated_date":"2013-12-30 09:10:22"
            }
         ],
         "followers":[
            {
               "f_id":"1846806385"
            },
            {
               "f_id":"100565"
            },
            {
               "f_id":"100001561"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}";

                   var serializer =
                        new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof (RootObject));
                    var context = (RootObject) serializer.ReadObject(jsonString);

myListBox.ItemSource = context.Task_details;
```

This should solve all problems.

Comment: Hi Stewart thanks for Your Reply , I know this and I done this in My code and im Showing Description Data and Date in List Box , But Im Unable to Show Followers , that y i post this Question , how to Bind Flowers list to this List Box

Comment: The followers should be in another ListBox or on another page. Then you can do something like var myTaskDetailFollowers = context.Task_details.First(t=>t.task_id == 3).Followers; and then myFollersListBox.ItemSource = myTaskDetailFollowers.

Answer (score 0):

JOSN data can be managed by using [JSON.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)  and [JSONORM](https://jsonorm.codeplex.com/). You can get it in Nuget by jsonorm

After getting data use data template in XAML. Here is an example. Create a window and paste this XAML.

```
<Window x:Class="DataTemplate.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="myTaskTemplate">
        <Grid Height="115" Width="456">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                          <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Foreground="#FF0079C3" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semilight" IsHyphenationEnabled="True" 
            LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding task_id}"/>

            <TextBlock  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="#FF7F7F7F" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semilight" 
            IsHyphenationEnabled="True" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" Text="{Binding alert}" TextAlignment="Left"/>

            <TextBlock  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="#FF7F7F7F" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semilight" 
            IsHyphenationEnabled="True" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" Text="{Binding task_description}" TextAlignment="Left"/>

                  <Path Grid.Row="3"  Grid.Column="0" Data="F1M8,2C11.314,2 14,4.686 14,8 14,11.313 11.314,14 8,14 4.686,14 2,11.313 2,8 2,4.686 4.686,2 8,2z" 
                Fill="#FF85F088" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.RowSpan="1" 
                Stretch="Uniform"/>

                   <Path Grid.Row="3"  Grid.Column="0" Data="F1M8,2C11.314,2 14,4.686 14,8 14,11.313 11.314,14 8,14 4.686,14 2,11.313 2,8 2,4.686 4.686,2 8,2z" 
                Fill="#FF85F088" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.RowSpan="1" 
                Stretch="Uniform" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.087,0.548" Margin="0,1,31,-1"/>
                   <Path Grid.Row="3"  Grid.Column="0" Data="F1M8,2C11.314,2 14,4.686 14,8 14,11.313 11.314,14 8,14 4.686,14 2,11.313 2,8 2,4.686 4.686,2 8,2z" 
                Fill="#FF85F088" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.RowSpan="1" 
                Stretch="Uniform" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.087,0.548" Margin="0,0,63,0"/>

        </Grid>


    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>



    <ListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Followers,IsAsync=True}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myTaskTemplate}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,13,0,0"/>
    <!---->
        <!--"" -->
```

Follow the Datacontext

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using InSync.appseconnect.Helper;
using ObjectDAL;
using jsonorm;


public class DataContext : ObservableObjectGeneric<DataContext>
{

    private List<Task_details> _taskdetaillist;

    public DataContext()
    {
        Followers = new Task_details().GetElementList("Task_details");
    }


    public List<Task_details> Followers
    {
        get
        {
            return _taskdetaillist;
        }
        set
        {
            _taskdetaillist = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Followers");
        }
    }

}
```

Following is the ObjectDAL

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using jsonorm;

namespace ObjectDAL
{
public class Comment
{
    public string task_comment_id { get; set; }
    public string f_id { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public string created_date { get; set; }
    public string updated_date { get; set; }
}

public class Follower
{
    public string f_id { get; set; }
}

public class Task_details : LocalStorage<Task_details>
{
    public string task_id { get; set; }
    public string created_f_id { get; set; }
    public string task_description { get; set; }
    public string due_date { get; set; }
    public string alert { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string postedon { get; set; }
    public string updatedon { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> comments { get; set; }
    public List<Follower> followers { get; set; }
}

public class TaskDetailList : LocalStorage<TaskDetailList>
{
    public int status { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<Task_details> Task_details { get; set; }
}
```

}