# Bind JSON to XAML-WPF

Tags: c#, json, wpf, xaml

I have a Json and I want to bind some values from the json in a wpf form. Some values should be passed in a simple text box but some others I need to bind them in an adjustable table depending on the json. 
My Xaml code is this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppTest1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="750" Width="525">
<Grid Name="Grid1">
    <Button x:Name="buttonPrint" Click="print_Click" Content="Print" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="340,621,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" Height="30"/>
    <Label x:Name="number" Content="Number" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="68"/>
    <Grid x:Name="nameCol" Height="260" Margin="45,240,382,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="name" Content="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,255,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60"/>
    <Grid x:Name="phoneCol" Height="260" Margin="145,240,282,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="phone" Content="Phone" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="175,255,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60"/>
    <Grid x:Name="addressCol" Height="260" Margin="235,240,192,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="address" Content="Address" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="265,255,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80"/>
    <Grid x:Name="emailCol" Height="260" Margin="365,240,62,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="email" Content="Email" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="365,255,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60"/>
    <Grid Name="table" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="288" Margin="40,242,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="430"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="number" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="118,20,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding number}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85" TextChanged="textBox_TextChanged"/>

</Grid>
```

I should have a Document Number which is in the beginning of the form and then a table which contains Name, Phone, Address and Email. I create four grids to use them as columns, but I don't know how many rows should I have because this will be depending by the json.

An example json is this:

```
{
"number": 123,
"person": [{
        "phone": 864556,
        "name": "John D",
        "address": "N.Y",
        "email": "test@test.com"
    },
    {
        "phone": 19845,
        "name": "Mary S",
        "address": "N.Y",
        "email": "testmary@test.com"
    },
    {
        "phone": 34936,
        "name": "Alex N",
        "address": "Santiago",
        "email": "alex@test.com"
    },
    {
        "phone": 097478,
        "name": "Bill McK",
        "address": "London",
        "email": "test@example.com"
        }]
    }
]}
```

So I first want to take the value from the number and then create the table with these data in my wpf form.

Has anyone any idea? I have found this [Deserializing nested JSON C# and Bind to XAML ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989311/deserializing-nested-json-c-sharp-and-bind-to-xaml-listbox) but I wasn' t be able to make it work properly in my case.

Until now I have done this. I am working on Visual Studio, so I have a MainWindow.xaml where is my XAML template and then in MainWindow.xaml.cs I have turn my json to C# and I have this

```
public class Rootobject
{
  public int number { get; set; }
  public Person[] person { get; set; }
 }

public class Person
{
public int phone { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
public string address { get; set; }
public string email { get; set; }
```

}

And also I have edit my Xaml like this for example

```
<TextBox x:Name="number" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="118,20,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding number}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85"/>
```

But when I start the application the textBox appears to be empty. Where should I upload the json with its values and should I do something different in my cs file?

Comment: Why not create a class to represent your data, then DeSerialize it with JSON.NET, then bind it to your UI? You can maybe DeSerialize your data to JObject, then bind your UI to that object, but the meaning of doing this? And for representing rows, create a DataGrid in you UI and bind rows to it.

Comment: I am very new to C# and I have to do it step by step. I create a class with my data in C# but I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: ```public class Person
    {
        public string phone { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
    }

    public class SingleRecord
    {
        public int number { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Person> person { get; set; }
    } ```

Comment: Yes this is what I have done until now. But now how can I pass these values in the right positions? For example in this 
    <TextBox x:Name="number" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" 
    Margin="118,20,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding number}" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85" 
    TextChanged="textBox_TextChanged"/> 

doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Read about binding in WPF yourself. You're asking to teach you.

Comment: I have read and I that's why I fix the json as you said. But I am not sure If I have write it in the right file or if I follow the right path. That's why I am asking. Because from those I have read, the last command should work, so there is somewhere a mistake.

Comment: This is a very silly assumption, I know. But have you set your window's DataContext somewhere? Because that's how WPF knows what to display.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio so I have a MainWindow.xaml (where is my form code) and a MainWindow.xaml.cs where inside the class MainWindow I have a public class RootObject with the json as c#. I don't know where should I put the json with the values.